# Is there any easier way to expand data.frame?

Tags: r, for-loop

I want to combind `data1`  and `region` . Currently, I use`for...`,the result as  `total_df`.
Is there any easier way for this ? Thanks!

```
data1 <- data.frame(category=c("a","b","c"),
                    amount=1:3)

region <- data.frame(country=c('US','UK'))


total_df <- data.frame()
for (country in region$country){
  data1$region <- country
  total_df <- rbind(total_df,data1)
}
```

Comment: Try `tidyr::crossing(data1, region)`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes !

Using rep, the code gets refactored, like this:

```
data1 <- data.frame(category=rep(c("a","b","c"),2),
                    amount=rep(1:3,2),
                    country=c(rep("US",3),rep("UK",3)))

> data1
  category amount country
1        a      1      US
2        b      2      US
3        c      3      US
4        a      1      UK
5        b      2      UK
6        c      3      UK
```